# What tag to use for optical networking?

Tags: discussion

There's already a [fiber](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fiber) for fiber questions, but I think we need another tag for optical networking (ROADM/DWDM/etc).  I suppose it could just be [optical-networking](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/optical-networking) but that's doesn't really roll off the tongue.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

I would suggest just using "optical". The -networking suffix seems redundant. I think that's clear enough in the context of the site. It should probably be combined with "dwdm" or other tag as appropriate for the specific technology involved.

Comment: In the absence of tag wiki excerpts, this use of "optical" .vs. "fiber" was completely non-obvious until I found this discussion over here in the meta-site. Simply appeared to be a mess of redundant tags - optical, fiber, optics, and one for passive optical networking.

I have submitted excerpts (without tackling the main Wiki entries, which is either a lot of work for stuff you can search on elsewhere, or subject to being a plaigairist if you take the easy route) for everything but optics, after finding this discussion. I still have no idea what "optics", as opposed to the other three, is.

Comment: In general, I'd like to suggest that if folks think a tag is a good idea, they take on the responsibility of making at least the tag wiki excerpt - this sector alone seems to be illustrating that the logic can be clear as mud when bare tags that have no obvious reason to be different are available.